# python find file type and save path and name to txt/csv

Tags: python

Can anyone help write a script, the goal is to find files with extension and save the name and path in TXT or CSV

that a script which find and print file file type and path,but how can i save the result to csv/txt ?

```
import fnmatch
import os
import csv

rootPath = '/'
pattern = '*.exe'
filepath = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/filetest.txt'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filepath in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        x = (os.path.join(root, filepath))
        print(x)
```

i try this one, but its save only the last line.

```
import fnmatch
import os
import csv

rootPath = '/'
pattern = '*.exe'
filepath = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/filetest.txt'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filepath in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        x = (os.path.join(root, filepath))
        file = open(filepath, 'w')
        file.write(x)
file.close()
print(x)
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `glob`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is you always open the file within loop using `open(filepath, 'w')` the option 'w' is always overwrite the file, if you want to append, you can use 'a', but I think in this case is not good solution because the main reason is you always reopen the file for each loop

By using your code, I think you can solve it by putting the open command outside the loop

```
import fnmatch
import os
import csv

rootPath = '/'
pattern = '*.exe'
filepath = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/filetest.txt'
file = open(filepath, 'w')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filepath in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        x = (os.path.join(root, filepath))
        file.write(x+'\n')

file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from glob import glob
import os

files = sorted(glob(os.path.join(rootPath, pattern)))

with open(filepath, 'w') as fid:
    fid.write('\n'.join(files))
```